How to traverse the pgd variable from mm_struct?
I'm using a barebones setup of Linux 6 with busybox.
All I wanted to do was simply traverse thru the PGD table, then into PMD table, and then in PTE table for the current process.
I've set a breakpoint at "context_switch" and try printing out "prev.mm.pgd". I do get an address, but its values are all 0's.
Could this be because whatever context_switch is referring to in it's prev and next arguments simply are not, or have not, concluded in creating any kind of page table?
Why would this be? And is there an easier way to read the PTE entries for a given process while debugging it with gdb and a qemu emulator?
I don't have much access to userspace as it is just a barebones filesystem with busybox. If it is recommended to extend userspace functionality so that I can use custom scripts in userspace I will reevaluate my current setup.
I just didn't think it would be that hard to find the array of pte entries while debugging with gdb and qemu.
